# JS - convert an array of objects to object such that the new object contains unique words

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object. Each object has two keys: id and text.

```
let o = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Dolorem"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "amet consectetur Dolorem"
  }
]
```

I need to convert this array to an object such that the object contains unique words. And the value of these words is a list containing id of the same object as word.

#### Result

```
{
  Dolorem:  [2, 3]
  Lorem: [1, 2]
  amet:  [1, 2, 3]
  consectetur: [1, 2, 3]
  dolor:  [1, 2]
  ipsum:  [1, 2]
  sit:  [1, 2]
}
```

How to do so?

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your any attempts and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the array. Trim, and split the text, and create a Set of word, to get only unique words. Iterate the Set with `Set.foreach()`, and add each word to the object if it doesn't exist. Push the current `id` to the word's array:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"},{"id":2,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Dolorem"},{"id":3,"text":"amet consectetur Dolorem"}];

const result = arr.reduce((r, { id, text }) => {
  new Set(text.trim().split(/\s+/))
    .forEach(w => {
      if(!r[w]) r[w] = [];
      r[w].push(id);
    });

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Ignoring case, and letters only:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"text":"Lorem 10 ipsum -- dolor sit amet consectetur"},{"id":2,"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit 20 amet! consectetur Dolorem"},{"id":3,"text":"amet consectetur Dolorem!!!"}];

const result = arr.reduce((r, { id, text }) => {
  new Set(text.trim().toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]+/g))
    .forEach(w => {
      if(!r[w]) r[w] = [];
      r[w].push(id);
    });

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you use new Set?

Comment: A word might appear twice in a sentence.

Comment: Where should i filter numbers and punctuations inside forEach or use JS filter method?

Comment: To filter out numbers and punctuations, use a regexp instead of split. For example, to catch only letters do `.match(/[A-Za-z]+/g)`. You might also want to change the string to lower case before splitting/match to ignore case.